# Only one media query is working, rest is ignored

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

Okay, so I have a couple of media queries at different break-points in my design.

For example

```
 @media all and (max-width:700px){
      body{
        background:red;
      }
 }
 @media all and(max-width:560px){
      body{
        background:blue;
      }
 }
```

It works fine on my desktop, but when I go to view it on my LG android browser, only the first media query triggers.

It doesn't have anything to do with the widths, because if I change the max-width of the first query to something less than 560 it gets triggered anyway.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the "all and"s:
http://jsfiddle.net/C3R9J/

```
 @media (max-width:700px){
      body{
        background:red;
      }
 }

 @media (max-width:560px){
      body{
        background:blue;
      }
 }
```

Take a look at Example 5 this link to WC3:
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

> if the media type is not explicitly given it is ‘all’.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with min-width. What it does: device width from 320px to 559px, device width from 560px to 699px, device width from 700px to XXX. The latest media type will overwrite all others media type.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    body { background:red; }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 560px) {
    body { background:blue; }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    body { background:green; }
}
```